# get value of clicked elements from document.selector

Tags: javascript

The following function "addTab" creates new tabs appending iframes in it when user clicks the element(label),how to pass/fetch the value/id in the function "addTab" from label.

```
 <label data-add-tab id="my_IdValue">my_IdValue</label>

 <script>
   var newTabs = new NewTabs()
   document.querySelector('label[data-add-tab]').addEventListener('click', _ => {
    newTabs.addTab({
      title: 'New Tab',
      favicon: false
    })
  })
</script>
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: ```document.querySelector('label[data-add-tab]').addEventListener('click', function(_) {
  console.log(this.id);
});``` If you do not need `Arrow-function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get it from event object, in your case it is `_`

```
<script>
  var newTabs = new NewTabs()
  document.querySelector('label[data-add-tab]').addEventListener('click', _ => {
    var id = _.target.id
    newTabs.addTab({
      title: 'New Tab',
      favicon: false
    })
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I'd add that _ is often used to imply that the argument does not matter, here it does matter so it should probable be renamed to event

Comment: yes it can be renamed to `e`, `event` or whatever developer wants

Comment: IMO, `Arrow-function` should be avoided in such use case where `this` matters :)

Comment: Rayon, in event listeners it's a bad practice to use `this` to get element instance, because this listener can be attached inside a class method, where you may want to refer the class using `this`

Comment: Thanks this is working great!, can i invoke a function at the very bigging of the script called opencity(value) in the same script ? is its possible ..

Comment: what is oencity(value)?

Comment: sorry for the typo, opencity(value) is another function in java-script in the same file

Comment: and what is the `value` argument in that function?

Comment: Yeah `var value=_.target.value` from your guidance